# Reading certain lines from a file in python without loading it in memory

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, file

I have a large csv file (90000 rows, 20000 columns). I want to read certain rows from it in Python using an index list. But i don't want to load the entire file using something like `"read_csv"` as this will fill up my memory and the program will crash. IS there any way to do it without loading the entire file?

I am open to changing the format of the input file(.csv) if that will help my case.

Comment: If each line of yourr file has the same size, you can use `seek` to advance to a specific position. But if the lines are variable size, you will need to iterate on `readline` either skipping a specific number of times or only check your predicate, and discarding the useless line without storing in any variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over the lines in a file without loading them all into memory at once using the standard `open` function.

```py
with open(my_file) as f:
    for line in f:
        ...
```

If you have a collection of line numbers you want to keep, you can capture just those lines with the following.

```py
lines_to_keep = {...}
with open(my_file) as f:
    lines = [
        line for line_num, line in enumerate(f)
        if line_num in lines_to_keep
    ]
```

This uses a list comprehension to iterate over the lines and their indices (thanks to `enumerate`), keeping only those lines whose index appears in the set (or other collection) `lines_to_keep`.

If you have a lot of lines to keep, you might want this slightly more verbose method, which avoids the excess line number checking present in the first method.

```py
lines = []
with open(my_file) as f:
    lines_iter = enumerate(f)
    for next_index in sorted(set(lines_to_keep)):
        for line_num, line in lines_iter:
            if line_num == next_index:
                lines.append(line)
                break
```

This method ensures uniqueness of the values in `lines_to_keep` and sorts them. Then, rather than checking line number membership against the whole collection, we can check only the next index in our sorted set.

In either case, you are left with a list of strings that you can pass to `pandas.read_csv` via an `io.StringIO` object.

```py
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("".join(lines)))
```

---

Inspired by rdas's answer, I've added the following as perhaps the most compact way to accomplish your goal.

```py
chunksize = 10_000
df = pd.concat([
    chunk.loc[chunk.index.intersection(lines_to_keep)]
    for chunk in pd.read_csv(my_file, chunksize=chunksize)
])
```

It is somewhat slower than both of the above methods in my testing (extracting 500 rows from a CSV file of 1,000 total rows) but is nicely readable.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation! This has worked for me on a test dataset.

Comment: But you still have to read every line in the file up to the one you're looking for. You read it in and then throw it away. Is there a way to just read in the exact line number that you want without reading in all the prior ones to get to it?

Answer (score 2):

to read certain rows from csv file use `skiprows` argument of `pandas.read_csv` function:

> `skiprows` list-like, int or callable, optional
>
> Line numbers to skip
> (0-indexed) or number of lines to skip (int) at the start of the file.
>
> If callable, the callable function will be evaluated against the row
> indices, returning True if the row should be skipped and False
> otherwise. An example of a valid callable argument would be `lambda x: x in [0, 2]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#io-read-csv-table) with [`chunk_size`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#io-chunking) to read the file partially into memory instead of completely.

Pseudocode:

```
for i in range(num_rows/chunk_size):
    reader = pd.read_csv('file.csv', chunk_size=chunk_size)
    for chunk in reader:
        # process chunk
        # if any of the indexes you want is present in this chunk, then grab it
```

Answer (score 0):

```
index_list = [22, 5013, 101394]
output_rows = []

with open('large_file.csv') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if i in index_list:
            output_rows.append(line)

print(output_rows)
```